# How can I change the mount with CMD commands?

Tags: command-line, mount

I have two files `*.CMD`, each of them makes the `G` Drive mount to different locations
using

```
NET USE G: "\\10.10......
```

I would like a single file to switch the mount path. How can I know to where my `G` Drive is connected at the moment?

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off & setlocal

(net use G: | findstr /b "Remote" | find "\\pathone" > nul) && goto :usetwo
goto :useone

:useone
    net use G: /y /d && net use G: \\pathone
    goto :eof

:usetwo
    net use G: /y /d && net use G: \\pathtwo
    goto :eof
```

`a && b` means that command `b` will only be run if `a` succeeds. (`a || b` will only run `b` if `a` does not succeed.)